# Javascript for loops to check interval overlap

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript function (Thanks to Nina Scholz).

```
function overlapping(a, b) {
function getMinutes(s) {
    var p = s.split(':').map(Number);
    return p[0] * 60 + p[1];
}
return getMinutes(a.end) > getMinutes(b.start) && getMinutes(b.end) >   getMinutes(a.start);
}
```

My problem now is that I have e.g. 4intervals:

```
var myArray = [{ start: '01:00', end: '04:00' }
{ start: '05:00', end: '08:00' }
{ start: '07:00', end: '11:00' }
{ start: '09:30', end: '18:00' }]
```

and now I will check if any interval overlap another one.

```
var overlap = false;
for(var n = 0; n < myArray.length; n++) {
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       var result = overlapping(myArray[n], myArray[i]);
       if(result == true) {
         overlap = result;
         break;
       }
    }
}
```

My question now would be if this is correct or if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: If you have tested the code, you should know if its correct.

Comment: if there are intervals [1-4][2-5][6-7][6-8] - what do you want to be returned? True, hours, intervals?

Comment: For starters, the `result` variable is redundant. You could put the result directly in `overlap`, then check `if (overlap) {break}`.

Comment: [1-4][2-5][6-7][6-8] -> [6-7] and [6-8] overlaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proposal witch checks all elements of the array against the others. If an overlapping is found, the iteration stops and `true` is returned. Otherwise `false`.

```js
function overlapping(a, b) {
    function getMinutes(s) {
        var p = s.split(':').map(Number);
        return p[0] * 60 + p[1];
    }
    return getMinutes(a.end) > getMinutes(b.start) && getMinutes(b.end) > getMinutes(a.start);
}

function isOverlapping(array) {
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            document.write('test ' + i + ' vs ' + j + '<br>');
            if (overlapping(array[i], array[j])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var myArray = [{ start: '01:00', end: '04:00' }, { start: '05:00', end: '08:00' }, { start: '07:00', end: '11:00' }, { start: '09:30', end: '18:00' }];

document.write(isOverlapping(myArray));
```